# android copy image from source to destination

Tags: android, file, copy

I am using the following code to copy image from source to destination

```
public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    if (destination != null && source != null) {
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    if (source != null) {
        source.close();
    }
    if (destination != null) {
        destination.close();
    }

}
```

I have been able to transfer almost 1500 images with this code, but one image was not completely transferred. Then upon searching i found this in the FileChannel android documentation " An invocation of this method may or may not transfer all of the requested bytes; whether or not it does so depends upon the natures and states of the channels. Fewer than the requested number of bytes are transferred if this channel's file contains fewer than count bytes starting at the given position, or if the target channel is non-blocking and it has fewer than count bytes free in its output buffer. " from this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom(java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long)). I want to know whether this is 100% assured way to copy image or should i use byte system to copy image. My images are in encrypted format. I have to copy them in the same way. Also i am deleting the original image when copied, hence i that one case i lost the image as it was not completely copied and i deleted the original. Thanks

Comment: Are you executing `copyFile()` in background thread?

Comment: i am using this code in an intent service

Answer (score 0):

You look ok.  Basically its saying that if the file you're copying is smaller than the size you specify, it will transfer the file and stop (it won't pad to the size you passed) which is what you want.  It will also stop if the destination is non-blocking and it would need to block to transfer more, but file channels by default are blocking.

Comment: can you please tell me that is this completely reliable way to copy images